# Remove special characters from data frame

Tags: r, regex, gsub, non-printing-characters

I have a matrix that contains the string "Energy per �m". 
Before the 'm' is a diamond shaped symbol with a question mark in it - I don't know what it is.

I have tried to get rid of it by using this on the column of the matrix:

```
a=gsub('Energy per �m','',a)
```

[and using copy/paste for the first term of gsub], but it does not work.[unexpected symbol in "a=rep(5,Energy per"]. When I try to extract something from the original matrix with grepl I get:

```
46: In grepl("ref. value", raw$parameter) :
input string 15318 is invalid in this locale
```

How can I get rid of all this sort of signs? I would like to have only 0-9, A-Z, a-z, / and '. The rest can be zapped.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this than with regex (e.g. by changing the `Encoding`).

But here is your regex solution:

```
gsub("[^0-9A-Za-z///' ]", "", a)
[1] "Energy per m"
```

But, as pointed out by @JoshuaUlrich, you're better off to use:

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "", x)
[1] "Energy per m"
```

Comment: `[^[:alnum:]]` is preferred to `[^0-9A-Za-z]`. Regarding the latter, `?regex` says "because their interpretation is locale- and implementation-dependent, they are best avoided." and "For example, `[[:alnum:]]` means `[0-9A-Za-z]`, except the latter depends upon the locale and the character encoding, whereas the former is independent of locale and character set."

Comment: Thanks. I only know that from being Ripley'd for using your first solution in a package. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Andrie, it turned out that I needed more characters, like .,()-? and space. Extending the regex or replacing it with [:alnum:]] or [[:print:]] gave strange results. The easiest solution was indeed to use encoding via iconv. This worked only after translating the column from factor to character. Phew...

Comment: @user580110 Do you care to post your `iconv` solution? I tried a few permutations, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Ah, and the culprit was the "euro" sign. Setting the wrong encoding zaps the parameters. Latin1 just leaves an empty space.

Comment: # remove non-printable characters
    raw$parameter=as.character(raw$parameter); 
    raw$parameter=iconv(raw$parameter,'Latin-9')

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace_all()` is an option if you prefer to use the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)

x <- 'Energy per �m'

str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "")
[1] "Energy per m"
```