# Remove Hex Code from String in R

Tags: r, string, text, replace, gsub

I have converted a .doc document to .txt, and I have some weird formatting that I cannot remove (from looking at other posts, I think it is in Hex code, but I'm not sure).

My data set is a data frame with two columns, one identifying a speaker and the second column identifying the comments. Some strings now have weird characters. For instance, one string originally said (minus the quotes):

```
"Why don't we start with a basic overview?"
```

But when I read it in R after converting it to a .txt, it now reads:

```
"Why don<92>t we start with a basic overview?"
```

I've tried:

```
df$comments <- gsub("<92>", "", df$comments)
```

However, this doesn't change anything. Furthermore, whenever I do any other substitutions within a cell (for instance, changing "start" to "begin", it changes that special character into a series of weird ? that're surrounded in boxes.

Any help would be very appreciated!

EDIT:
I read my text in like this:

```
df <- read_delim("file.txt", "\n", escape_double = F, col_names = F, trim_ws = T)
```

It has 2 columns; the first is speaker and the second is comments.

Comment: how are you reading the text file into R? I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: df <- read_delim("file.txt", "\n", escape_double = F,  col_names = F, trim_ws = T)

Comment: How did you convert your .doc to .txt?

Comment: @Dason, I resaved the word document to plain text within Word.

Comment: can you try running `print.listof( read_delim("file.txt", "\n", escape_double = F, col_names = F, trim_ws = T))` and see if it is encoding correctly? I assume you're using Windows which is why I can't reproduce the error

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your help, but unfortunately the document still looks the same

Comment: do you know how your document is encoded? The default in R is UTF-8

Comment: @Chris, I'm not sure--is there a way to find that out? If so, I'd be happy to check.

Comment: @J.Sabree unfortunately not really. You can open the file in notepad and chose UTF-8 when you go to save it.

Comment: You can choose the encoding when saving as .txt within Word.

Comment: Hi all! I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970891/r-remove-special-characters-from-data-frame

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here: [R remove special characters from data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970891/r-remove-special-characters-from-data-frame)

This code worked: gsub("[^0-9A-Za-z///' ]", "", a)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. This code will remove these special characters such as the ' in don't and will be lost from the data - you would be better off trying to change the encoding in R if that is an issue.